# Including another window forms with in an "Iframe" in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to include another form in my code instead of constantly contacting the other form and making the form move with each other, which takes a lot of time to code in each form. And now I need something that takes less time and is much easier to do, like putting one windows form inside another windows form

**EDIT**: Unclear Question
I want to display a windows form inside another windows form,
just the same functionality as an `Iframe` in `HTML`, but instead

of including a web page I want it to include a form

Comment: Can you maybe assume your audience doesn't know anything about your project?  Very unclear what problem we are trying to solve here.

Comment: Make the child form TopLevel property false and then add it to the form's control collection.  Or look into the MDI interface, but that is a dated technology.

Comment: @LarsTech Without MDI how would you design an application with over 50 different forms, where the users want to be able to have more than one form open at the same time ?

Comment: @GuidoG Tabbed Interfaces.

Comment: @LarsTech does that allows more than one form to be opened next to each other  so the user can see them for comparing or whatever he wants to do ?

Comment: @GuidoG I'm not sure why you are trying to rub my rhubarb.  If you are putting 50 different forms in front of the user at the same time, that's not a good gui.  If you have just two forms, you can use a SplitContainer.

Comment: @LarsTech I am not trying to rub anything I am just wondering. And it is not the idea to put 50 forms open at once, The application happens to have over 50 forms. The idea is that the user can open more than one at the same time. For example opening 2 different orders to compare them and while he has them open he can open for example an invoice form to answer a question to somebody on the phone...  For that an MDI is perfect. So I was just wondering how to do that without MDI. Splitcontainer seems so odd to me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

MDI interface would be best, but if you really want to do this then look at this : (formFrame is the form that is shown inside formHost)

```
formFrame.TopLevel = false;
formHost.Controls.Add(formFrame);
formFrame.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
formFrame.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; // can be different for you needs
formFrame.Show();
```